# IIS smooth streaming does not play a video on asp.net MVC 4 with Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, smooth-streaming, smooth-streaming-player

I am trying to get a basic demo working but can't succeed, I've spent hours and hours on it..

I am building an iis smooth streaming player with no controls at first that auto plays the video, I am using "MMP"- Microsoft media platform which was formerly "SMF"- Silverlight media framework, the example I am using to build a smooth streaming player is here on the middle of this page: http://smf.codeplex.com/documentation

A brief explanation of the issue I am facing:
I am sure I got everything right in terms of the player itself, I got the .ism file, i can view its manifest if I browse to it with the browser, I can even get everything to work and play the video in an html file that is running straight from an IIS website.
another key note: I can also run any test silverlight application for example, the main form with a button and a few radio buttons and I do get this application to run and display. the problem happens only when I try the smooth streaming player, it gives a black and blank page for the whole page and right clicking shows "silverlight".

so the problem starts when I try to run it from a Silverlight application that is hosted in an asp.net MVC 4 (with Razor) application. 
I have an asp.net MVC project in visual studio and then I add a silverlight application to it and choose to host it in the MVC application, then I follow the same routin as for the silverlight application player building and it even renders and plays the video on the visual studio's silverlight XAML design page. I build the whole solutio and then I get a "silverlightApplication1.xap" file in a "ClientBin" new folder on the MVC application and also a test html file and an test aspx file again in the MVC application.

if I make sure the linking is correct I can take this html file to another IIS website and run it from there and it works and plays! but if I try to run it straight from within the application (view in browser) for the html/aspx files it says that it's not running on the platform/fabric of the website and for the silverlight application itself it opens the same blank silvelight application with a black screen and also a URL of file:// and not `http://localhost..` etc', so what I was trying to do for a long time is to make the silverlight application work as a view in the MVC application.

so I took a view and deleted everything in it and gave it a property of Layout=""; (nothing) and then I put the content of the test html file the SL application produced earlier, modified the value for the silverlightapplication path etc', when built and ran, the page comes up, even the application comes up as I see "Silverlight" on a right click of the mouse but the whole screen is just plain black again and it doesn't play the video.
I had the .ism file on anther location or a an entirely different location like another online website.

I also can't get to view the manifest when I run the MVC application it says its 404 but I am not sure if it's an MVC platform thing that it won't let me get to it or it's just not getting to it but the files are there and the URL's are correct both in the code and also in the URL i am putting in.

I have also came to the understanding that I might need to make sure the silverlight application is allowing cross domain traffic and it has a Client access policy like seen on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250(VS.95).aspx , so I've added two XML files to the root folder for these two issues. trying to figure out what's going on with firefox's web developer gives nothing as for what happens..

Please Help! Thanks! :)

Ray.

Comment: Briefly, what exactly doesn't work? Also you should add a code where you call the Silverlight application from the MVC view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why and I have tried everything+making sure I get the manifest content if i browse to it.

it just worked with this URL for the ism file:

```
http://video3.smoothhd.com.edgesuite.net/ondemand/Big%20Buck%20Bunny%20Adaptive.ism/Manifest
```

there was no need for cross domain xml and Client access policy xml.